# Android Management API - some android device does not provide serialNumber

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am working with Android Management API to fetch device serialNumber.

Some devices like Samsung A30, Samsung Active Tab 3, etc provides device serial number. But some devices like Redmi Pro 10 and SamsungSM-G781B do not provide the device serial number.

I have provided this to the **management app policy**.

```
{
    "installType": "REQUIRED_FOR_SETUP",
    "permissionGrants": {
        "policy": "GRANT",
        "permission": "android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    },
    "autoUpdateMode": "AUTO_UPDATE_HIGH_PRIORITY",
    "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
    "packageName": "com.example.management",
    "delegatedScopes": [
        "CERT_INSTALL"
    ]
}
```

I have provided this to **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
```

Here is the code,

```
  fun getDeviceSerial(applicationContext: Context): String {

            var serialNumber: String = ""

            try {
                val c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties")
                val get = c.getMethod("get", String::class.java)

                serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "gsm.sn1") as String

                when (serialNumber) {
                    "" -> serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "ril.serialnumber") as String
                }

                when (serialNumber) {
                    "" -> serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "ro.serialno") as String
                }

                when (serialNumber) {
                    "" -> serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "sys.serialnumber") as String
                }

                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                when (serialNumber) {
                    "" -> serialNumber = Build.SERIAL
                }

                when (serialNumber) {
                    "" -> serialNumber = ""
                }

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                serialNumber = ""
            }

            if (serialNumber == "unknown") {
                try {
                    val c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties")
                    val get = c.getMethod(
                        "get",
                        String::class.java,
                        String::class.java
                    )
                    serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "ril.serialnumber", "unknown") as String
                } catch (ignored: Exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        "ignored ${ignored.message}",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    )
                        .show()
                }
            }
            try {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O && serialNumber == "unknown") {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            applicationContext,
                            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
                        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {
                        serialNumber = Build.getSerial()
                    } 
                
                } 
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                 serialNumber = ""
            }
       

            return serialNumber
        }

        fun openTelePhony(context: Context?) {
            context?.let {
                var a = ""
                try {
                    //check permission
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            context,
                            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
                        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {
                        a = getDeviceSerial(context)
                   
                    } else {
                        a = Build.SERIAL
                       
                    }
                    System.out.print(a)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    System.out.print()
                }
            }
        }
```

I tryed above code to get device serial no from android management api.

Comment: if you got serial can you help me with this code

Answer (score 0):

You can add more than devices by calling ADB shell getprop and reading any unique value.

Also you can find some changes maybe help you to find device serial or unique value.

```
       when (serialNumber) {
            "" -> serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "ril.serialnumber") as String
        }

        when (serialNumber) {
            "" -> serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "ro.serialno") as String
        }

        when (serialNumber) {
            "" -> serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "gsm.sn1") as String
        }

        when (serialNumber) {
            "" -> serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "sys.serialnumber") as String
        }
        when (serialNumber) {
            "" -> serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "ro.boot.serialno") as String
        }
        when (serialNumber) {
            "" -> serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "ro.ril.oem.sno") as String
        }
        when (serialNumber) {
            "" -> serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "ril.cdma.esn") as String
        }
        when (serialNumber) {
            "" -> serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "vendor.gsm.serial") as String
        }
        when (serialNumber) {
            "" -> serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "ro.boot.un") as String
        }
        when (serialNumber) {
            "" -> serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "ro.boot.uniqueno") as String
        }
        when (serialNumber) {
            "" -> serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "ro.ril.oem.wifimac") as String
        }
        when (serialNumber) {
            "" -> serialNumber = get.invoke(c, "ro.ril.oem.btmac") as String
        }
```